# How to create mat-table with sorting with data obtained from HttpClient (Angular)

Tags: angular, http

I'm new to angular and I'm having a hard time understanding how I can display data obtained from HTTP requested into a sorted mat-table. Currently what I'm doing is in my app.component.ts I have a getdata method:

```
  getdata() {  
    this.ServiceService.getData().subscribe((data: any[]) => {  
      this.data = data;  
    })  
  }
```

this is the method it calls from ServiceService (Simple API call)

```
getData(){
  return this.http.get('/api/Employee');
}
```

and in my app.component I have:

```
  constructor(private ServiceService: ServiceService) { }  
  data: any;  
  EmpForm: FormGroup;  
  submitted = false;   
  EventValue: any = "Save";  
  
  ngOnInit(): void {  
    this.getdata();  
  
    this.EmpForm = new FormGroup({  
      eId: new FormControl(null),  
      eName: new FormControl("",[Validators.required]),        
      eAddress: new FormControl("",[Validators.required]),  
      eEmail:new FormControl("",[Validators.required]),  
      eAge: new FormControl("",[Validators.required]),  
    })    
  }
```

Then in my app.component.html I just do this

```
<div class="row">
      <table class="table table-striped">
          <tr>
              <td>Id</td>
              <td>Name</td>

              <td>Address</td>
              <td>Email</td>
              <td>Age</td>
              <td>Edit</td>
              <td>Delete</td>
          </tr>

          <tr *ngFor="let d of data">
              <td>{{d.eId}}</td>
              <td>{{d.eName}}</td>

              <td>{{d.eAddress}}</td>
              <td>{{d.eEmail}}</td>
              <td>{{d.eAge}}</td>
              <td><a (click)="EditData(d)" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a></td>
              <td><a (click)="deleteData(d.eId)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
```

This works fine, but I've been banging my head trying to change my normal table into a mat-table with sorting, I'm unsure how I can load this data (*ngFor) into my mat-table, if mat-table is the right choice at all (I just need sorting). Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use mat-table for your data.

You can refer to this link: https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples
(See an example of Data table with sorting, pagination, and filtering.)
and for your BE data-binding to table :

In your typescript file, you just have to create a variable like

```
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<UserData>;
```

and in your function add like this:

```
    getdata() {  
    this.ServiceService.getData().subscribe((data: any[]) => {  
      this.data = data;  
      this.dataSource.data = data;
    })  
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry I know this is pushing it, but how do I call the data in mat table. 
i.e is this correct?
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="eId">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let d"> {{d.eId}} </td>
</ng-container>     
              </table>

Comment: I am not getting your point. But did you see that example of the material table?  https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples (See an example of Data table with sorting, pagination, and filtering.)  In that example for rendering they have used  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>. You just have to integrate that code in your code.

Comment: I apologize, confused myself with something silly, I figured it out now. Although now I'm running into an entirely different issue with building the project (I'm having a hard time importing material into my project.) 
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts:17:15 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MatTableDataSource'.

17   dataSource: MatTableDataSource<UserData>;
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/app.component.ts:17:34 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'UserData'.

17   dataSource: MatTableDataSource<UserData>;

Comment: you may refer this link for your problem: https://medium.com/@sstarx/angular-material-getting-started-67e148dfea7e

Comment: Thank you Shubham, you're the real MVP. It fixed on of the errors im getting, but I'm still kind of stuck because I keep getting : Cannot find name 'UserData'.

19   dataSource: MatTableDataSource<UserData>;

I have this in my component:

Comment: Am I supposed to replace the UserData in MatTableDataSource<UserData> with something else? Because that's where the error occurs, not sure if its an import error or just me misunderstanding that variable.

ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts:19:34 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'UserData'.

19   dataSource: MatTableDataSource<UserData>;
                                    ~~~~~~~~

I'm so sorry for bothering you with all this, it's okay if you can't know.

Comment: Here UserData is the model name. You may replace it with <any>

Comment: Thank you man you're a real legend. Wish I had something to give back, have a nice day

Comment: Man, you got me out of a painful headache. (See [here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/27708) ). Thank you!